# After find all solutions, how to score the solution and choose one

Tags: prolog

Here is the questions, setof returns a set of solutions

```
solve([A1, A2, A3, B1, B3, C1, C2, C3, T]):-

    permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [A1, A2, A3, B1, B3, C1, C2, C3]),

    T is A1 + A2 + A3,

    A1 + A2 + A3 =:= A1 + B1 + C1,
    A1 + A2 + A3 =:= A3 + B3 + C3,
    A1 + A2 + A3 =:= C1 + C2 + C3.
```

Then I find all solutions

```
?- setof(Z,solve([A1,A2,A3,B1,B3,C1,C2,C3,T]),Set).
A1 = 1,
A2 = 4,
A3 = 8,
B1 = 7,
B3 = 3,
C1 = 5,
C2 = 6,
C3 = 2,
T = 13,
Set = [_G5594] ;
A1 = 1,
A2 = 5,
A3 = 6,
B1 = 8,
B3 = 4,
C1 = 3,
C2 = 7,
C3 = 2,
T = 12,
Set = [_G5578]
...
```

How do I to filter and score results to find the solutions has max T value (15)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use **CLP(FD) constraints** for such combinatorial tasks.

For example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solution([A1,A2,A3,B1,B3,C1,C2,C3], T):-
        [A1,A2,A3,B1,B3,C1,C2,C3] ins 1..8,
        T #= A1 + A2 + A3,
        A1 + A2 + A3 #= A1 + B1 + C1,
        A1 + A2 + A3 #= A3 + B3 + C3,
        A1 + A2 + A3 #= C1 + C2 + C3.
```

The exact details vary a bit between Prolog systems, so check your system's manual for more information. The maximum can be obtained via **labeling options**, such as:

```
?- solution(Vs, T), labeling([max(T)], Vs).
Vs = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
T = 24 ;
Vs = [7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8],
T = 23 ;
Vs = [7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7],
T = 23 ;
etc.
```

See [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more information.

You can *commit* to the first solution with `once/1`.